# Break out of loop if GPIO doesn't toggle in time

Tags: python, timer, raspberry-pi, interrupt, gpio

I'm changing some inputs to a device with relays, and I'm expecting at some point to break the firmware.  The question is, when will this happen?

So, to determine if the firmware breaks, I'm monitoring some LEDs that normally blink during normal operation.  I know that they will lock up in whatever state they're currently in when the firmware breaks.  So, my bright idea was to simple feed that signal back into a Raspberry Pi and watch the that GPIO for a change-state.  If I see the state change, then go ahead and flip the relays...Then look at the LEDs and make sure they're still blinking...rinse, repeat.

However, I would normally check this with an interrupt or something in C, but I'm writing this in Python...

What's the Python way for handling this?  I know that if I don't see any blinking for 2 seconds or so, the test is over, but I'm not sure how to do this without invoking something like `sleep`...to which, I wouldn't be able to watch for pin changes.

Comment: Have a look at [`signal.alarm()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) for example.

Answer (score 0):

From the [gpio](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/) module, create a threaded callback function that fires every time a rising (or falling, etc...) edge is detected.

Then using [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) within this function call `signal.alarm()` to reset an alarm whenever the pin changes.

Finally use `signal.signal()` to register a function for what should happen when the alarm is not reset in time (ie, firmware has broken)

*this won't work if you're using windows unfortunately... you would need to implement your own alarm system with threading if you are*

Comment: This is pretty good...As I got more into it, I went a slightly different route:

Comment: While (not_broken)

{  Do the manipulations

GPIO.Wait_for_falling_edge(timeout=x seconds)

if/else statement to break the loop

}